# How to set Title in Navigation drawer 2018

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, titlebar

Hey guys new to all this and can't seem to figure a way to change the Navigation Title with my navigation drawer selection. Made a stock standard navigation drawer with android studio.

I feel it's really simple but hope someone will give me an answer.

i watch a youtube 2014 by Derek Banas and all he added in his fragment class was

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(2);
    }
```

but that doesnt seem to work anymore. is there something similair for Studio 3.0.1?

Comment: easy enough, for those who don't know or couldn't find a reference  like me all you have to do is under MainActiviy in the onNavigationItemSelected add setTitle("Title name")  at the else if statement you want. so easy.

Comment: more stupid questions to come :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to Android Studio, create New Project with the Navigation Drawer template, in MainActivity, you'll find the method **onNavigationItemSelected**. In that method, you can easily change activity title depending on your navigation option selection -

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
            setTitle("Camera");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            setTitle("Gallery");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            setTitle("Slideshow");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
            setTitle("Manage");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            setTitle("Share");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
            setTitle("Send");
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Please accept if it helped solve your problem. That ways others can know that the answer was correct and accepted. Thanks. :)